# Extract data from facebook

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, text-mining, social-network-analysis

I am learning about social media analysis. I am aware that we can extract the data from twitter using hashtags and API. Ex; If I use `#covid19`, I will get all tweets that contain this hashtag for the duration that I specify.

Similarly, let's say I visit a public Facebook page `https://www.facebook.com/A123`

Will I be able to extract **only** the posts which contain the term `covid` in their text (from all of their posts) using my API credentials?

Is it possible? I don't like to extract all the posts from the page `A123`. However, I only wish to extract **only** the posts which contain the term `covid` in their text (from all of their posts)

Can you help me on how can it be done?

Any tutorial/tools available to extract this info?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its called **graph-api**.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v7.0/page/feed

You should be aware that scraping data from facebook not using this api its
violation of the regulations of fb laws and could you be ended with ban. So be careful.

Comment: Yeah, I will only be using fb's API credentials. So, you say it's possible to extract specific posts (with a certain keyword) from all the posts present in a timeline. Am I right? btw, upvoted

Comment: can you direct me to a resource on where it shows on how to extract posts which contain specific keywords?

Comment: I cannot use the post id as mentioned in this https://medium.com/@DrGabrielHarris/python-how-getting-facebook-data-and-insights-using-facebook-sdk-9de14d3c12fb. Hence asking yoyu

Comment: I am thinking that you should start get token :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/